# Is there a way to document parameters of a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

Say you have this function :

```
/**
 * doSomething description
 * @param {function} fn - A function that accepts an argument.
 */
function doSomething( fn ) {
    fn.call(this, 'This is a test');
}
```

And doSomething should be used like this :

```
doSomething( function( text ) {
    console.log( text );
});
```

**My question is :**
Is there an official way in JSDoc to document fn parameters ?
May be something like :

```
/**
 * doSomething description
 * @param {function} fn - A function that accepts an argument.
 * @param {string} fn( name ) - A text passed to the fn function.
 */
function doSomething( fn ) {
    fn.call(this, 'test');
}
```

Comment: No you won't find anything like that in JSDoc. Flow and TypeScript on the other hand...

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv : Thank you so much, but is there a workaround or something ?

Comment: There's `@callback` though, maybe it's not a big deal to you that JSDoc thinks it's a callback :) http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#callback-functions - this way at least you can specify parameter types.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv : I've seen that before posting the question, and I just don't like the way it separates the two functions.
To be honest, I've never heard of Flow before.I looked it up on google and it seems cool.Thanks to you I'll start learning Flow . You are AWESOME :)

Comment: Flow is _awesome_ :) I've switched to TS myself because it brings a lot of other cool things besides strict type checking but if that's all you need then Flow should be plenty enough. Good luck with it!

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv : You know what, since you've switched to TS after using Flow, I'm gonna start learning TS. Thanks for the advice. Keep it up :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SergiuParaschiv mentioned in his comment, the only way to do that is using the [@callback](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-callback.html) tag like so :

**Javascript code :**

```
/**
 * A function to be passed as an argument.
 * @callback doSomethingCallback
 * @param {string} text - A simple text.
 */

 /**
  * doSomething description
  * @param {doSomethingCallback} fn - A function that accepts an argument.
  */
 function doSomething( fn ) {
     fn.call(this, 'This is a test');
 }
```

**JSDoc result :**

[image: JSDoc result]